# How do i specify parent Application context from XML?

Tags: java, spring

I need to re-use an already existing context as a parent in springs.

I have 2 xml files - **bean.xml (parent context), child-bean.xml (child context)**

I can do

```
ApplicationContext context2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "child-bean.xml" }, context);
```

But this approach is via code. 
Is there any way to control this via XML ?

I tried putting this in **child-bean.xml**

```
<import resource="bean.xml"/>
```

but its not the same, because it looks like all the beans in the parent are being created again.

*TL;DR*

I need to make sure the new instances of the beans in the parent are not being created again when the child context is being created. Is this possible via XML without changing the way the Application Context is being initialized ?

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml you can load multiple Application Contexts using:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:bean1.xml,
        classpath*:bean2.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I don't have a web.xml, its a standalone java application.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
     public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException{
        XmlWEbApplicationContext applicationContext = 
       new   XmlWebApplicationContext();
       applicationContext.setConfigLocation("classpath:spring/*.xml");
       container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(applicationContext));
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i use ref parent

i hope my xml configuration help you

```
<!--parent -->
<bean id="abstractService" abstract="true"
        class="com.lizjason.spring.AbstractService">
        <property name="companyName"
            value="lizjason"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="shippingService"
        parent="abstractService"
        class="com.lizjason.spring.ShippingService">
        <property name="shippedBy" value="lizjason"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I'm not talking about a parent bean here, i'm talking about a parent application context